# Verification of computation involving Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

[Image of question][1]

I have attempted the question linked below. I apologise for not being able to post an image directly in my post.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/996yR.png

I have attempted it and would appreciate if someone could verify my solution:

(a) Define $T_{AJ}$ to be the time taken by AJ to perform his jobs. Then we have that $\mathbb{E}(T_{AJ})= 50 \times 20 = 1000$. Also, $\mathrm{Var}(T_{AJ})=10^2 \times 20 = 2000$. Thus, we have that $$\mathbb{P}(T_{AJ} < 900) \approx \Phi\left(\dfrac{900-1000}{\sqrt{2000}}\right) = 0.0127.$$

(b) Define $T_{MJ}$ to be the time taken by MJ to perform his jobs. Then we have that $\mathbb{E}(T_{MJ})= 52 \times 20 = 1040$. Also, $\mathrm{Var}(T_{MJ})=15^2 \times 20 = 4500$. Thus, we have that $$\mathbb{P}(T_{MJ} < 900) \approx \Phi\left(\dfrac{900-1040}{\sqrt{4500}}\right) = 0.0184.$$

(c) The quantity of interest is $\mathbb{P}(T_{AJ}<T_{MJ})$. To compute this, we first find the expectation and variance of $T_{AJ}-T_{MJ}$. We have that $\mathbb{E}(T_{AJ}-T_{MJ})=-40$ and $\mathrm{Var}(T_{AJ}-T_{MJ})= 6500$. Thus, the requested probability is computed as $$\Phi\left(\dfrac{0-(-40)}{\sqrt{6500}}\right)=0.690.$$

Comment: It looks fine :-), although the thumb rule for applying clt is that the number of random variables are greater than $30$.

Comment: Thank you for checking! Unfortunately, I don't have the solution for this question and one solution I found online seems to be strange to me: https://resumeprofessionalwriters.org/qa/a-j-has-jobs-that-she-must-do-in-sequence-with-the/ - so I don't know the intended approach. This problem is from S. Ross 8th Edition.  Thank you for telling me about the thumb rule for applying the CLT - I didn't know about that.

Comment: The online solution is strange for me as well. Your solution makes much more sense than the other one.